# How to edit a file you don't own >

Tags: linux, software-rec, text-editors

I need to edit `/etc/lirc/lircd.conf`

Problem is it is owned by root, and I can only open it as read only.

How can I open it for editing ? Please note I'm new to Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in the sudoers file, you can edit the file by typing `sudo vim /etc/lirc/lircd.conf` ([sudo](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sudo)) into your console. Another way is to just become root in your current shell: `su root` ([su](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?su)) once you are root, then you can edit the file normally.

Comment: forgot to mention I'm using ubuntu, gui :)

Comment: If you want to edit it via a gui, open up a shell and type gksudo gedit /etc/lirc/lircd.conf Most linux distributions don't allow you to log in as root via the GUI by default, so you have to use a shell to promote yourself to root.

Comment: I don't think it's very wise to suggest a "complete linux noob" to use vim to edit a file?

Comment: Another point, ubuntu 10.10 seems to create a root account for you, but never mentions the password for it. So when prompted for password from a SU root, I have no idea what the password is.

Comment: Default root password: http://nixcraft.com/ubuntu-debian/13249-what-default-root-password-ubuntu.html#post19639  You can also change it by typing sudo passwd root

Comment: @Muhammad To be honest, I don't know what text editors are installed by default, so I picked vim.

Answer (score 3):

Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press <kbd>F2</kbd>, it'll invoke the "run" dialog. Type in "gksu gedit /etc/lirc/lircd.conf" (without the quotes) [mind the forward slash / as opposed to the backslash \ that you typed in your question]. It'll ask for root password. Enter password and hit enter. It'll open the file. Make changes and save file (click button or do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu: Easy (And Quick) Ways To Open Any Files As Root](http://maketecheasier.com/ubuntu-easy-and-quick-ways-to-open-any-files-as-root/2008/02/19)

Comment: Thanks but this is still a bit over my head, being a day 1 noob. Anyways, I don't think Linux is really ready for noobs yet. its a pitty.

Comment: Anyone who's a noob to computers finds windows or mac os difficult too I'm sure. If you haven't used linux before, then you just discover you have to do things in it entirely differently than your previous os (esp windows). It's just different. Not too difficult. Try to unlearn your previous ways and start afresh. And it'll be just fine. And just so I'm not mistaken for an expert of any sort, I'm very much a noob.